# iOS Xcode 4 properties access

Tags: xcode, ios, xcode4, accessor

I switched to Xcode 4 recently and I don't really understand this new way to write accessors.
For example, in the application delegate class that is auto-generated when creating a new project, the `window` object is not declared in the `@interface` but just this way:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
```

Then, in the implementation file, we have the `@synthesize window=_window;`.
And in the functions, we have either `self.window` OR `_window`.

For example:

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; // in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function
[_window release]; // in dealloc function
```

Can you explain me the difference, why there is nothing in the `@interface`, why we do `@synthesize window=_window;` instead of `@synthesize window;` and what is the difference between `self.window` and `_window`, I mean when do I have to call one more than the other?

I'm a bit lost, and feel like the new code I doing trying to do the same in not working properly...

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. "Why is there nothing in the `@interface`"

   The runtime is synthesizing the ivar for you.
2. "Why do we do `@synthesize window=_window;`

   This means that the `window` property will use an ivar named `_window` (by default the ivar name is the name of the property)
3. "What is the difference between `self.window` and `_window`?"

   The former is using the `window` "getter" method (ie, `foo = [self window]`), and the latter is accessing the ivar directly.
4. "Why do I have to call one more than the other?"

   It is generally considered unsafe to use accessor methods in your `dealloc` method, which means using the ivar is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Xcode 4. This is Objective-C 2.0 (which Xcode 4 uses by default when creating project templates).

I recommend reading the chapter on properties in [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html), that should make things much clearer

And doing things "the old way" will still work. You don't have to change everything overnight, simply remove the auto-created code if you don't like it, until you feel comfortable with the new syntax.

Comment: Yes, I have read all the Objective-C Programming Language guide, I was remembering the `@synthesize window=_window;`. Just needed some update on that to make my mind very clear and you guys helped me. Thanks @puzzle for the additional information!